# Bad GSM network automated testing

Tags: rf, gsm, automation

We are using a 2G modem controlled by an MCU in our device and we want to do an automated test routine that tests our firmware for bad mobile network scenario. How can we create a system where a computer like Raspberry Pi can through software both 'tamper' and 'restore' GSM signal so that the RSSI drops and increases as controlled by software?

We are looking for creating scenario no network connectivity at all, barely any network (say -90 dBm to -100 dBm) and good network (> -70 dBm). Note that GSM antenna connection is through a U.FL connector by using a decent antenna we get -60 dBm in our location.

Comment: Is the Raspberry Pi the MCU that controls your modem, or is it separate?

Comment: A programmable or stepped attenuator in series with your antenna, or someplace else in the the RF path seems like a logical starting point.

Comment: Do have to test with the antenna connected?  If not, couldn't you just use a RF signal generator that can generate a proper GSM signal?

Comment: Is this a test that is to be performed on every piece of production equipment, or is it a single device that tests production software? because if it's the latter blow the modem off the board and emulate all it's functions with the PI or or suitable computer.

Comment: You need to quantify your pass/fail criteria.

Comment: @SteveSh There is a separate MCU, not R-Pi. Also, we can figure out how to alter the antenna, but not by GSM signal generation since we want to test with the telecom provider we are using.

Comment: @Bryan If its easier to tamper the GSM signal, we don't want to invest in emulating the modem under all conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consider altering the environment instead of the equipment:**

How about get any kind of linear actuator and slide metal plate over the device:

[image]

Or a hinged metal box, open and close with a servo:

[image]

Comment: Note that these only lead to reproducible test conditions if the unit under test is precisely positioned as well.

Comment: @BenVoigt indeed, position likely to be very important.  The idea of "manipulate the environment" is the key one, so it's in some way a genuine tes of different environments.  You could alternatively impair the _antenna_ by blocking it in the same way.

Comment: "How about get any kind of linear actuator and slide metal plate over the device:".  You would have to calibrate that setup to determine signal level/attenuation vs position.

Comment: @SteveSh certainly you'd have to do some calibration, but the question is suggesting only three settings: none, barely, and good.  None=fully enclosed, Good=fully exposed, "barely": have to test it a bit.

Comment: @jonathanjo we tried this manually a few days back with a steel utensil box maybe half mm thick. The RSSI was decreasing by 10 to 20 dBm, not enough for no or barely enough signal.  Will the thickness of the shielding box change this?

Comment: @EarthLord - You were probably getting leakage through the seams & hinge joint.  Even a small crack can ruin your expected attenuation.

Comment: @EarthLord Yes the quality of the seams will affect it too, probably a lot more than the thickness.  See [faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) for some thoughts.

Comment: @EarthLord how has it turned out?  were you able to get the results you needed?

Comment: @jonathanjo we haven't had the time to implement this yet. Will comment here once we have results.